# How to add multiple values to numpy array

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

How do I add it to a numpy array like this?

```
[[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]]
```

So it becomes:

```
[[2, 4 6]
[5, 7, 9]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked the obvious?

Comment: I did arr = list + arr, and it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What happened when you did? Edit your question to include that info.

Comment: You must have had some typo. I typed exactly this `a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]); b = [1, 2, 3]; print(b + a)` and got the result you wanted.

Comment: And don't call your variables `list`, you are shadowing built-in list type.

Comment: `l2 = [l[1], l[0]] + l[2:]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6]])

print(a+b)
```

Result

```
[[2 4 6]
 [5 7 9]]
```

Explanation, that's how broadcasting works.

- Take first dimension of the bigger matrix **b**
- Add row by row the lower dimension vector **a**